# Problem with running of undetected_chromedriver on Linux(Gentoo)

Tags: python, linux, webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

i'm a new developer by Python and at this time i don't have enough experience to solve this problem. I have a problem when i'm starting the module `undetected_chromedriver` on Linux(Gentoo)

I'm using : `undetected_chromedriver` version = `3.1.5r4`, Python version = `3.8.5`

I also created a `local_variable` to link to the chromedriver file.

```
export CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/path_to_chromedriver/node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver'
```

This is the Python script I am running:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as UC_1
UC_1.TARGET_VERSION = 100
options = UC_1.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = UC_1.Chrome(driver_executable_path = os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'), options=options, service_log_path= dir_name + '/chromedriver.log', use_subprocess=True)
```

When i start the script, it raises this error:
`(python script is running with logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG))`

Info from console:

```
INFO:undetected_chromedriver.patcher:patching driver executable /path_to_chromedriver/node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver
DEBUG:uc:created a temporary folder in which the user-data (profile) will be stored during this
session, and added it to chrome startup arguments: --user-data-dir=/tmp/tmp_fypdc2_
DEBUG:uc:did not find a bad exit_type flag

Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ea_test.py", line 219, in <module>
    driver = UC_1.Chrome(driver_executable_path = os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'), options = options, service_log_path = dir_name + '/chromedriver.log', use_subprocess = True)
  File "/path_to_env/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 392, in __init__
    browser = subprocess.Popen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1627, in _execute_child
    executable = os.fsencode(executable)
  File "/usr/lib/python-exec/python3.8/../../../lib/python3.8/os.py", line 806, in fsencode
    filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Please, could you tell me, where a i make a mistake? And how i can solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are providing an empty value to the uc initializer. I believe that it may be related to your environment variable "CHROMEDRIVER_PATH".

I had this same problem some time ago, my issue was that I was passing arguments to ChromeOptions in an invalid way.

PS: Remember that there is uc.v2 version now, with better flow.